# how to know if the app was launched by clicking on the push notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to know if there is a flag and parameter that can tell me if the user launched the activity/app by clicking on the push notification in the notification tray.

My code in C2DMReceiver.java

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();

        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent notificationIntent = manager
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        **notificationIntent.putExtra("fromRemote", true);**

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.icon = R.drawable.icon;
        notification.tickerText = message;
        notification.number = badge;
        notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Draw Something", message,
                pendingIntent);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

I tried setting

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("fromRemote", true);
```

but when the app was launched there were no extras in the intent.

my code in the onCreate function of my mainactivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        print("onCreate - bundle has extras");
        for (String key: extras.keySet())
        {
          Log.v ("mytag", "MainActivity onCreate key =" + key);
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.v ("mytag", "onCreate - bundle has NO extras");
    }
```

The output i get is onCreate - bundle has NO extras. So the extras are not getting passed through.

So is there any other way?? It is so easy in iOS

Comment: Just post something to the server when your `Receiver` get called :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity

Comment: thanks Urban - tried searching all kinds of formats of questions for this :)  - it worked

Answer (score 2):

Just posting an answer so that people who visit this page get the solution.

You need to use `putExtra(ID_KEY,id)` when you create your Intent for starting your application, and in your onCreate() method you can use `getIntent().getExtras().getInt(ID_KEY);` to retrieve your passed id integer.

The passed extra could be anything, a boolean, String etc.

Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7358692/3036759

Comment: Except that for Firebase push 'notification' messages the app doesn't get called until the notification has already been clicked on. Which means you don't get to set any id.